# How I Can Send Image I capture Using Camera 2 Api android to Server using Retrofit

Tags: java, android

I Build A camera 2 On Android And I Save the Image Once the Activity Open After 3 Second I take a Picture a save it on Device I try to Send the Image to server Below is my Code for Camera and API ,

TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener textureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
//open your camera here
transformImage(width,height);
openCamera();
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
// Transform you image captured size according to the surface width and height
}
@Override
public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
return false;
}
@Override
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {
}
};
private final CameraDevice.StateCallback stateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
@Override
public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
//This is called when the camera is open
Log.e(TAG, "onOpened");
cameraDevice = camera;
createCameraPreview();
transformImage(textureView.getWidth(),textureView.getHeight());
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
takePicture();

```
            }
        },3000);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
        cameraDevice.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
        cameraDevice.close();
        cameraDevice = null;
    }
};
final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallbackListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
        super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        createCameraPreview();
    }
};
protected void startBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread = new HandlerThread("Camera Background");
    mBackgroundThread.start();
    mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundThread.getLooper());
}
protected void stopBackgroundThread() {
    mBackgroundThread.quitSafely();
    try {
        mBackgroundThread.join();
        mBackgroundThread = null;
        mBackgroundHandler = null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void takePicture() {
    if(null == cameraDevice) {
        Log.e(TAG, "cameraDevice is null");
        return;
    }
    CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    try {
        CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraDevice.getId());
        Size[] jpegSizes = null;
        if (characteristics != null) {
            jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);
        }
        int width = 640;
        int height = 480;
        if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
            width = jpegSizes[0].getWidth();
            height = jpegSizes[0].getHeight();
        }
        ImageReader reader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.JPEG, 1);
        List<Surface> outputSurfaces = new ArrayList<Surface>(2);
        outputSurfaces.add(reader.getSurface());
        outputSurfaces.add(new Surface(textureView.getSurfaceTexture()));
        final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
        captureBuilder.addTarget(reader.getSurface());
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_AUTO);
        // Orientation
        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
       // captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
        captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Date date = new Date();
        final File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+date.getMinutes()
                +date.getSeconds()+"pic.jpg");
        ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener readerListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
                Image image = null;
                try {
                    image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.capacity()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);
                    save(bytes);
                    System.out.println("Image Object File" + image);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (image != null) {
                        image.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            private void save(byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
                OutputStream output = null;
                try {
                    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    output.write(bytes);
                } finally {
                    if (null != output) {
                        output.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        reader.setOnImageAvailableListener(readerListener, mBackgroundHandler);
        final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureListener = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(CameraCaptureSession session, CaptureRequest request, TotalCaptureResult result) {
                super.onCaptureCompleted(session, request, result);
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Saved:" + file, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                UploadImage uploadImage = new UploadImage();
                uploadImage.setFile(file);
                RequestBody requestFile =
                        RequestBody.create(
                                MediaType.parse("image/jpg"),
                                file
                        );
                MultipartBody.Part body =
                        MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("files[0]", file.getName(), requestFile);
                Call<UploadImage> call = RetrofitClient.getmInstance().getApi().upload(body,
                        SharedPrefManger.getInstance(getApplication()).getToken());

                call.enqueue(new Callback<UploadImage>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<UploadImage> call, Response<UploadImage> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 204){
                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, response.body().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {

                            Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Upload Error: " + response.message(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<UploadImage> call, Throwable t) {
                        System.out.println("Error F: " + t.getMessage());
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                //Intent x = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                //startActivity(x);
                createCameraPreview();
            }
        };
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(outputSurfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                try {
                    session.capture(captureBuilder.build(), captureListener, mBackgroundHandler);
                } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Code Interface to Connect Api   @Headers("Content-Type:multipart/form-data")
    @Multipart
    @POST("user/rest/upload/uploadSingleFile")
    Call<UploadImage> upload(@Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                             @Header("token") String token);

Comment: UploadImage is a model have Object File file  and setter and getter